# how to make validation using ajax Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.3, ajaxform

I am using Laravel 5. In my OrganisationsController I have a method addItem

```html
 public function addItem(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = array(
            'nom' => 'required',
        );
        // for Validator
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails())
            return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));

        else {
            $section = new Section();
            $section->nom = $request->nom;
            $section->save();
            return response()->json($section);
        }
    }
```

> Ajax code

```html
    $("#add").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/addItem',
                data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'nom': $('input[name=nom]').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        $('.error').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.error').text(data.errors.title);
                        $('.error').text(data.errors.description);
                    } else {
                        $('.error').remove()
                        $('table').append("<tr class='section" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.nom + "</td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-nom='" + data.nom + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-nom='" + data.nom +  "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>"); }
                   }
                });

            $('#noom').val('');
        });
```

> html code

```html
<div class="form-group row add">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="noom" name="nom"
               placeholder="New section here" required>
  <p class="error text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" id="add">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add new Section
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

I don't know why my validation not work. Please suggest a example for this. I am using laravel 5. I have searched so many sites. But I cannot get solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your validations fails it will return with a status code (error code) of `422`.

In your `$.ajax` you're only using `success` which won't be called if your validation fails.

You will need to add an error method to your ajax options. Using your above code you would have something like:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('.error').remove()
    $('table').append("<tr class='section" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.nom + "</td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-nom='" + data.nom + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-nom='" + data.nom + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>"); 
},
error: function (data) {
    if (data.errors) {
        $('.error').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.error').text(data.errors.title);
        $('.error').text(data.errors.description);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it still in the same problem :(

Comment: i found the **solution** !!!
the solution is remove the condition **if(data.errors)**
**thanks for help**

Answer (score 1):

for jquery 3 and above, use this code

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/addItem',
      data: {
           '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
           'nom': $('input[name=nom]').val()
      }
}).done(function(data){
      //if success, do this
      console.log(data);
      alert('success');
}).fail(function(jqXHR){
      if (jqXHR.status == 422) {
             var errors = (jqXHR.responseJSON);
             console.log(errors);
      }
});
```