# How can I do automatic validation email laravel?

Tags: forms, laravel, validation, email, laravel-5.3

I use laravel 5.3

My view blade like this :

```
<form id="form-register" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
    ...
    <div class="{{$errors->has('email')?'form-group has-error': 'form-group'}}">
        {{Form::label('email', 'Email'), ['class' => 'control-label'])}}
        {{Form::email('email', old('email'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email')}}
        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="error error-server help-block">Please Enter Your Valid Email</span>
        @endif
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

My validation like this :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users'
    ];
}
```

It works

If I enter an email that is already in the database table, then I submit, it will appear message validation email invalid

But I want to change it to automatic validation

So if the user inputs an existing email in the database table, it will automatically appear message validation email invalid

How can I do that?

Comment: If I undestand well, you want the input in your HTML to check if the user type an existing email in your form ?
If it is, you will need to add ajax request to check the input.

Comment: As @EkinOf said, you can do it with ajax call on change action in email input field.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40422363/how-to-make-validation-using-ajax-laravel-5-3) answer, did that using AJAX

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd, I want to check email after user input in input text. Not after click submit button

Comment: You try to answer with detailed answers

Answer (score 1):

on your input changes, you need to send an Ajax request to the backend, this request will reach an API that will check the existing of the requested email.

Comment: You try to answer with detailed answers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to display the exact error message returned by Validator for email field

You can get the first error message returned for email by call this `$errors->first('email')`

Here is an example

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
  <span class="error error-server help-block">{{$errors->first('email')}}</span>
@endif
```

Comment: I don't think he want to display the exact error message.
What OP try to do is, to check dynamically if the email already exist to alert user before pressing submit.

Comment: @Digitlimit, I want to check email after user input in input text. Not after click submit button

Comment: In that case you need to use jQuery. There many jQuery plugins for this